# What Gym exercises should i do to reduce weight instead of shaping muscles?

Tags: weight-loss, exercise, gym

I am 5 feet and 4 inches high. I am weighing 83kg these days. My tummy has bulged out, looking bad. I am caring for my diet, having lemon water in morning. But now i want to do gym exercises to reduce weight. 
I have seen many people having good shaped body but they look bulky, even they have 6 packs but their tummy looks fat similar is for legs and biceps, triceps. I have also seen skinny people with good shaped bodies. By skinny i mean [this](https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=skinny%20men&biw=1366&bih=613&tbm=isch&imgil=QznUZtMRX3gaNM%253A%253BVA7su8Qvd3sK4M%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fnextluxury.com%25252Fmens-health-and-fitness%25252Fhow-to-gain-weight-supplements-for-skinny-guys%25252F&source=iu&pf=m&fir=QznUZtMRX3gaNM%253A%252CVA7su8Qvd3sK4M%252C_&usg=__PZ96N-AgVyWL3s0XQltikfCA010%3D&ved=0ahUKEwjtrL2bos7OAhUMXh4KHYG9Cb4QyjcIKg&ei=KmW3V-3vLIy8eYH7pvAL#imgrc=QznUZtMRX3gaNM%3A) 
**Question:** 
How to do exercise in gym to look like skinny body? Which exercises i should do? Is this possible what i am asking? Having skinny body, does that depend on exercises you do or on nature of your body?

Comment: It's almost exclusively depended on diet. You can vary the rep ranges to focus on strength or hypertrophy, but diet is always the main factor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are putting too much emphasis on the exercise portion of your goal. You say that you are "caring for your diet" by drinking lemon water in the morning. The number one way to change your body composition is going to be your diet.

If you are not already tracking your daily calorie intake, you should start. This will be the most effective way to produce better results. If you are looking to get skinny and avoid building much muscle, you need to be in a calorie deficit to induce weight/fat loss. You can use MyFitnessPal for this, it becomes pretty easy once you get used to it. I have all of my clients use it to track their' diets.

As for the exercises, you can have a mix of weight training and cardiovascular exercise. Assuming you stay in a calorie deficit, you are not going to build a lot of muscle mass, which it seems you are trying to avoid.

Comment: Thanks Milo for your valuable answer.Is there an estimate about how much calorie deficit per day is safe? By "safe" i mean,not feeling tired all day just because i am calorie deficit. How much my body can endure this deficit without feeling tired?

Comment: It is going to depend on how much fat you need to lose and what body fat percentage you are looking to get down to. You can find some examples of body fat percentage here: http://www.builtlean.com/2012/09/24/body-fat-percentage-men-women/ Basically, the higher body fat you are to start, the more of a deficit you will be able to handle without feeling bad. There are a lot of calorie calculators out there but one of the easiest things I have found is to just multiply your bodyweight by 13. This will give you a good calorie intake to start off with.

Comment: If you are losing between 0.5-1.5 lbs per week, stick with it. If you aren't losing that much, you can drop another 100-200 calories from your daily intake and keep adjusting as you go. The larger your deficit becomes, the worse you will feel. So, sticking with a small deficit like I laid out will ward off any bad side effects of being in a deficit!

Comment: @MiloMartinovich - If you have a personal link, please do not put it in your answers. You may place it in your profile, and if you reference the site in an answer, you need to disclose that it is your personal site. Otherwise, your posts may get marked as promotional/spam.